# Why does Mozilla's borderify example extension does not work on some webpages (youtube, reddit,

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

Mozilla has a plethora of browser extensions included at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Examples. One of them is "Brorderify", which has a content script that adds a border to page matches:

[image]

I have matches set to `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]`, the border is added to most sites (google searches, twitch, ucla.edu) but not on all sites. I found that it does not work on youtube, or reddit. How are they blocking it?

I can see the content script when I open the debugger and there are no console errors.

[image]

Inspecting the body shows that their is a border, even though we can't see it.

[image]

Deleting the  `<ytd-app>...</ytd-app>` tag will actually show the border.

[image]

How is the border covered or not displayed?

Comment: What does the development console say? Any errors on that page? Is the content script included there?

Comment: @TimWißmann I see the content script included when I open the debugger. There are no console errors at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the element selector and hover of the body tag, you'll see that the body tag is only showing a very small portion of the page. The other elements are overlayed on top of the body using absolute position. Youtube have some weird custom tags that sets it's style as absolute position over the body.

[image]

Looking at this ytd-app tag, on the right you can see the style is set at {position: absolute, top: 0, right: 0} which sets right on top of the body. There's some other tags that does the same at different positions...It's a huge mess.

If you set the boder on this tag, you will see a border on the right side but not all of it. There are other tags that is overlayed on top. Probably a tag overlayed absolute position for the side bar, another for the app bar and etc.

Comment: Additionally, the body tag does not has a height (nor position property set) so it is not rendered correctly and neither does the border.